# How to load data quickly into app that is fetched from firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, local-storage

[image: Issue]I'm a rookie Android developer and learning daily. And now I got an issue that troubles me from a week.

In my app I use firebase firestore to load data(*mostly images and textviews*). And this works fine but now I found a issue in my app when the user opens the app the data that's fetched from firestore happens again and again even the data is same. This increases my read operations in firebase also it takes time to load the data into their fields. So, to give a quick response to user I want to load the data from locally.

So, I want to know how can I do that. How can I save the data from firestore and load from local storage which makes it quick and easy.

Explanation: I tried cache loading and it worked well but when the user I clear the app data and open the app again then the data isn't fetching from the server like it happens earlier. So, is there a way to check if cache is empty loaded from server if cache is there load from cache.

**Example Code:**

```
Source source = Source.CACHE;

    if (user != null){
        user_id = user.getUid();
        DocumentReference reference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").document(user_id);
        reference.get(source).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                DocumentSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
                if (snapshot != null) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()){
                        name = String.valueOf(snapshot.get("Name:"));
                        editName.setText(name);
                        email = String.valueOf(snapshot.get("Email:"));
                        editEmail.setText(email);
                        mobile = String.valueOf(snapshot.get("Phone:"));
                        editMobile.setText(mobile);
                        dob = String.valueOf(snapshot.get("Date of Birth:"));
                        editDOB.setText(dob);
                    }else {
                        editName.setText(user.getDisplayName());
                        editEmail.setText(user.getEmail());
                        editMobile.setText(user.getPhoneNumber());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

In the above code when I move from parent activity to this activity at first the edit text fields are empty and after 3 seconds they get their values. but when i used **Source.CACHE** then it loads quickly but when i removed cache or login from other account the same cache appears.

So, how can i quickly load data.

Comment: Where are your images stored? In Storage? Firestore? Somewhere else?

Comment: I store them in storage and use the link and load them from firestore.

Comment: There's no built-in way (Firebase SDK) to cache storage. Caching storage would be challenging in some cases as the cache could then overwhelm the device. You will need to craft your own caching technique.

Comment: My real issue that I'm trying to convey is how can I load the data quicker. Currently the get(); calls that I make takes a one or two seconds delay till the incompletelistener complete. So reduce that time i have to do something that works perfectly. And that's the reason why I posted this question. So, please help me in that.

Comment: Understood. Code being 'slow' may be related to how you wrote the code, the types of calls, your structure, your internet or a myriad of other things. We really need to see what code is 'slow' to be of any help. This site is for coding specific questions and example code is pretty much a requirement. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show some code and we'll take a look!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Source Options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#java_4) to read from the local cache. From that link:

> For platforms with offline support, you can set the `source` option to control how a `get` call uses the offline cache.
>
> By default, a get call will attempt to fetch the latest document snapshot from your database. On platforms with offline support, the client library will use the offline cache if the network is unavailable or if the request times out.
>
> You can specify the source option in a `get()` call to change the default behavior. You can fetch from only the database and ignore the offline cache, or you can fetch from only the offline cache. For example:
>
> ```
> // Source can be CACHE, SERVER, or DEFAULT.
> Source source = Source.CACHE;
>
> // Get the document, forcing the SDK to use the offline cache
> docRef.get(source).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
>     @Override
>     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
>         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
>             // Document found in the offline cache
>             DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
>             Log.d(TAG, "Cached document data: " + document.getData());
>         } else {
>             Log.d(TAG, "Cached get failed: ", task.getException());
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```

Comment: If I use the source what about the real-time updates that firestore offers and my app works online and won't allow user to go offline, I'm using cache only to load data quickly instead of +2-3 seconds delay due to server communication.

Comment: If you're having a hard time making your code work, edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce your situation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The OP is using Storage for the images.. will this still work?

Comment: I honestly couldn't figure it out from the question anymore, which is why I asked for an MCVE. Caching is possible with Storage too, but there's nothing built into the SDK for it.

Comment: Updated my question please check